# php Jquery Ajax autocomplete for dynamicaly added textbox

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I haw a webform where one field in each row of a table has a Jquery AutoComplete function and this works fine.
I also add rows to this table dynamically with a ajax call.
the problem is I can't seem to get the autocomplete to work on the dynamically added row(textBox).
Based on google "all" i need to do is add the .autocomplete to the added field. I haw tried different variants of this and it seems that jquery cant find the field to add it?

Add row code:

```
$(".btnAddRow").click(function(){
var count = $(this).closest('.AgensDiv').children('.count').val();
var tab = $(this).closest('tr').find('.tab').val();

count++;

$.ajax({
    url: "tblRow.php", 
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "HTML",
    data: {"count": count,
        "tab": tab},
    success: function(result){
        //console.log(result);  
        $("#agensTbl tr:last").before(result);

    }});    
$(this).closest('.AgensDiv').children('.count').val(count);             
});
```

Autocomplete code:

```
$(".legemiddel" ).autocomplete({
source: function( request, response ) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "AgensSok.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {"Virkestoff": request.term},
        success: function(data){
            response(data);
            //console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(error){
             console.log("Error:");
             console.log(error);
        }
    });
},
minLength: 3,
select: function( event, ui ) {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.atc').val(ui.item.id);
    //$("#testAjax").val(ui.item.id);
 },
 open: function() {
   $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
 },
 close: function() {
   $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
 }
});
```

tried different variants of adding the autocomplete or just changing the value of the textbox in the newly added row

```
$("#agensTbl tr:last").prev().find(".legemiddel").val("popp");
```

changes the value of the row before the newly added on and

```
$("#agensTbl tr:last").find(".legemiddel").val("popp");
```

does not work
haw tried adding the autocomplete code but I am guessing the problem is accessing the newly added row.
also tried giving the new textbox a uniqe ID just to test. with no success.

So how do I access the added rows members?
or is there a way to add the autocomplete to a higher level? (document.body) alle the textBoxes that I wish to use autoComplete on haw the class "legemiddel"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I changed the autocomplete code to the following, and this seems to work.

```
$(document).on("keydown.autocomplete", ".legemiddel", function(e){
$(this).autocomplete({
source: function( request, response ) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "AgensSok.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {"Virkestoff": request.term},
        success: function(data){
            response(data);
            //console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(error){
             console.log("Error:");
             console.log(error);
        }
    });
},
minLength: 3,
select: function( event, ui ) {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.atc').val(ui.item.id);
    //$("#testAjax").val(ui.item.id);
},
open: function() {
  $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
},
close: function() {
  $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
}
});
});
```